# Нейронная сеть Хопфилда

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети

Нейронная сеть Хопфилда хранит 0.15 образов. У меня в лабе сеть на 16 нейронов, обученная на 4 вектора по 16 бит. То есть она запомнит только 2. Я правильно понимаю?
И еще вопросик, если ей подать сильно зашумленный образ, то она зацикливается и y(t+2) = y(t). Все бы казалось хорошо и работу сети можно останавливать, но "гоняет" она эти 2 образа, на которые не обучалась. Что это значит? Что она не распознала образ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добрый день. Плотно занимался сетями хопфилда несколько лет назад, сейчас могу что-то подзабыть. Но ответы примерно такие:

1) 0.15 образа это в идеале, если образы полностью некоррелированные. Посмотрите корреляцию ваших образов, возможно сеть их просто "не тянет".

2) сеть по своей динамике когда попадает в локальный минимум при каждой итерации начинает инвертировать образ. То есть когда она что-то распознала (верно или не верно, не важно), следующей итерацией она инвертирует результат. Ну а ещё следующей выдаёт снова тот же.
Поэтому y(t+2) = y(t).

Другой вариант ответа на второй вопрос - у неё сформировалось два одинаково губоких минимума и она по ним и прыгает.

В любом случае, советую использовать что-нибудь похитрее обычной сети хопфилда :)
Как минимум гетеро-ассоциативную сети хопфилда, трёхслойную. У неё гораздо больше ёмкость памяти (скорость работы и обучения пониже, но при таких объёмах данных это будет незаметно).
Если интересно, могу про неё рассказать :)

Comment: спасибо не надо, просто мне надо было лабу сдать...